# pandas: to_dict("records") rounded incorrectly

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to convert a pandas DataFrame to a list of dictionaries in which 1 dictionary represents 1 row; therefore pandas `to_dict(orient='records')` method is perfect; however the output is incorrectly rounded in some cases. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1/3, 2/3], y=[4/3, 5/3]})
#            x         y
   0  0.333333  1.333333
   1  0.666667  1.666667

df.round(3).to_dict(orient='records')  # rounded incorrectly
# [{'x': 0.3330000000000002, 'y': 1.333}, {'x': 0.6670000000000004, 'y': 1.667}]

df.round(3).to_dict(orient='list')  # rounded correctly
# {'x': [0.333, 0.667], 'y': [1.333, 1.667]}
```

As you can see `to_dict(orient='list')` seems to work fine. What's the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure, on 0.18.1 it seems same for both?

Comment: I'm using 0.20.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas 0.20.2 for some reason `orient = records` uses the numpy float type and the `orient = list` uses native python float type.

```
records = df.round(3).to_dict(orient='records')
print(type(records[0]['x']))
numpy.float64

list_orient=df.round(3).to_dict(orient='list')
print(type(list_orient['x'][0]))
float
```

The difference in the exact data type results in the rounding difference.
Now why the different orient arguments result in a different datatype, I cannot say.

When converting the numpy float back to native python float:

```
print(float(records[0]['x']))
0.333
```

We get the output like in the list oriented to_records output.

For some more info about weird float shenanigans [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Is this just for `0.20.2`? If I upgrade to the most recent version will this be fixed?

Comment: I have no idea if upgrading to the latest version will fix this. I explicitly mentioned in 0.20.2 since John did not this behaviour in 0.18.1.